# Nested SQL query with multiple tables

Tags: jquery, sql

I am trying to return the supplier name and product name from tables "suppliers" and "products" for the product with the max price. So far, this is what I have. I know I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure what as both parts of my query work separately.

```
SELECT suppliers.SUPPLIERNAME, products.PRODUCTNAME, products.PRICE
FROM PRODUCTS, SUPPLIERS
WHERE SUPPLIERS.SUPPLIERID=PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID
AND procuct.price=(SELECT MAX(Price)
from products);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of comments and a possible solution.

> 1) You have spelling mistakes. You've misspelled your table names.
>
> 2) That's not how you join 2 tables
>
> 3) You're joining your Product Ids with your Supplier Ids.  That can't be right. Your PROUCTS table ought to have some SUPPLIER_ID or something. Or some 3rd table to join those 2 or something like that.

```
/*
DECLARE @PRODUCTS TABLE (PRODUCTNAME varchar(10), PRICE int, PRODUCTID INT);
INSERT INTO @PRODUCTS VALUES
('Shoes', 10, 1),
('Pants', 123, 2),
('Socks', 30, 3);

DECLARE @SUPPLIERS TABLE (SUPPLIERNAME varchar(10), SUPPLIERID INT);
INSERT INTO @SUPPLIERS VALUES
('Adidas', 1),
('Nike', 2);
*/

SELECT s.SUPPLIERNAME, p.PRODUCTNAME, p.PRICE
FROM @PRODUCTS p
    JOIN @SUPPLIERS s ON s.SUPPLIERID = p.PRODUCTID
WHERE p.price=(SELECT MAX(Price) from @PRODUCTS);
```

Remove the @ in front of the tablenames to make it work for you.
Just keep in mind that this is still probably wrong because you probably shouldn't `JOIN` your tables based on `PRODUCTID = SUPPLIERID`